# Having difficulty giving system.net.ipaddress a value

Tags: vb.net

I want a format check to validate IP Address entered by user.But I dont know how to use IPAddress class so how would I give address an Value so my tryparse will return an value.
I am trying to give address an value but I am quite unsuccessful

```
Private Function validateIpaddress() As Boolean

        Dim address As IPAddress
        address = 192.168.0.1

        Return IPAddress.TryParse(tbIPaddress.Text, address)

    End Function
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this below. You can't set the address to that multi-dotted "number" which won't even parse in VB. You have to create a string that gets passed to the TryParse method and the IPAddress is an output parameter of that method.

```
Private Function validateIpaddress() As Boolean
    Dim address As IPAddress
    'Dim addressString As String = "192.168.0.1"
    Return IPAddress.TryParse(tbIPaddress.Text, address)
End Function
```

You also may want to pass the address into your function as a parameter if you need to validate multiple addresses.

Comment: I just noticed you were checking a TextBox value there. I somehow glossed over that. You don't need to define a string at all then. Your problem was probably just trying to incorrectly set the IpAddress to `192.168.0.1`.